# Django-filter doesn't filter

Tags: django, django-filter

Hi I'm new in django and I want to use django-filter for url filtering in django-resframwork but i can't get my data filtered.

views.py

```py
class ListingFiltered (generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer    
    filterset_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend)
    # filterset_class =  ListingFilters
    filterset_fileds= ['price']
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('listings/', ListingViewSet.as_view(), name= 'listings'),
    path('listings/custom', ListingFiltered.as_view())
]
```

serializers.py

```py
class ListingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
```

I'm trying `http://127.0.0.1:8000/listings/custom?price=1000` and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: corrected `filterset_field`

Comment: You have a typo here: `filter_fileds`. Should be `filter_fields`

Comment: @viam0Zah sure you ment `filterset_fields`, tried that already